# How to get entire column from database and store it in an array using php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My table's name is userdetails, it has four attributes named name, username, mobile and password. I want to get all the mobile numbers and store it in an array using php.
I have used the following php code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$mobile  = $_GET['mobile'];
$sql = "SELECT MOBILE FROM USERDETAILS";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

 $result = array();

 array_push($result,array(
 "MOBILE"=>$res['MOBILE']
 )
);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

  }
```

but all I am getting is the first entry of the database.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through the records by doing the following:

```
$result = [];
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $result[] = $array['MOBILE'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting all number of column use while loop as

```
 $jsonData = array();// initialized you array
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {// add MYSQLI_ASSOC to get associative array
        $jsonData[] = $res['MOBILE'];// store data into array
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonData);// convert in into json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$mob = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $mob[] =  $row['MOBILE'];  
}
```